# Show ALL items in order in Mongodb database

Tags: database, mongodb, find

For some reason when I run  db.products.find().pretty(), it doesn't list all the items in my database, and the ones it does list are not in order. Any idea why or how to list everything? It does give me the option to run 'it' after to show more, but it still doesn't show them all or in order. I just want to see all 100 products in order and pretty().

I can understand it not being on order, of productId, because I may not know to do so, but at least can I get it to list everything??

Comment: Is this being run from Mongo Shell ?

Comment: Yes it is being run on the Shell

Answer (score 2):

for setting order you can use `sort()`.

```
db.sortData.find().sort({id:-1}).pretty()
```

here, -1 = Descending Order and 1 = Ascending Order on `id` field of collection.

By Default, mongo shell batch size returns 20 records at a time, then show more have to enter, if you want to changes size you can fire this command.

```
DBQuery.shellBatchSize = 30
```

so, now 30 records of collection mongo shell returns rather than 20.